# Calling vb.net function from javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

**what I want to do is call a vb.net function from javascript**

here is my html code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Untitled
        Page
    </title>
    <script
    src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script
        type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
            $("button").click(showVbHelloWorld)
            function
            showVbHelloWorld()
            {
            window.external.showVbHelloWorld();
            }
            })

            </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button>A</button>

</body>

</html>
```

**and here is my vb.net code**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Security.Permissions

<PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")> 

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(True)>

<Microsoft.VisualBasic.ComClass()> 

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _

        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.WebBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = Me

End Sub

Public Sub showVbHelloWorld()

    MsgBox("Hello")

End Sub

End Class
```

still on button click im geting error

**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'showVbHelloWorld'**

sorry for my uneven formatting of the code...i am new to stackoverflow...

Comment: Why are you using Javascript. Why not just use .NET event handling????

Comment: im basically working on javascript...but i want to convert some of my html content to pdf using HiQpdf http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertHtmlToPdf.aspx
and HiQpdf provides c# and vb.net codes thats why i am trying this way...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link that shows how to do it: [Call VB method from JavaScript](http://forums.asp.net/t/1393756.aspx)

It basically says there are 2 ways, Ajax or Postback.  Here is the postback method:

aspx file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 function callServersideFunction()
 {
  var someValueToPass = 'Hello server';

 __doPostBack('CustomPostBack', someValueToPass);
 }
 // -->
 </script>
```

aspx.vb file:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  ' Insure that the __doPostBack() JavaScript method is created...
  Me.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Me, String.Empty)


 If Me.IsPostBack Then
   Dim eventTarget As String
   Dim eventArgument As String

  If ( (Me.Request("__EVENTTARGET") Is Nothing)
    eventTarget = String.Empty
   Else
    eventTarget = Me.Request("__EVENTTARGET"))
   If ( (Me.Request("__EVENTARGUMENT") Is Nothing)
    eventArgument = String.Empty
   Else
    eventArgument = Me.Request("__EVENTARGUMENT"))

  If eventTarget = "CustomPostBack" Then
    Dim valuePassed As String = eventArgument
    ' Call your VB method here...
   End If
  End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to put this statement

```
Me.WebBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = Me
```

inside `form_load`

```
Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.WebBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = Me
End Sub
```

see this site:-
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35373/VB-NET-C-and-JavaScript-communication